# How to fix "452: out of range pointer: 0x100010 Ubuntu 23.04" error when burning USB with Rufus?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, 23.04, rufus

I burned Ubuntu to a flash drive using Rufus 4 and burned it again using Rufus 3.13, but the following error persists:

> 452: out of range pointer: 0x100010 Ubuntu 23.04

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Check if your USB stick is big enough. Verify the downloaded ISO file against the md5sum file that you can find in the same location as the  ISO file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem when I used ventoy

Answer (score 2):

When using Rufus 4.x, did you let Rufus download the GRUB 2.06 files it needed?
You should have been prompted with this message that told you that Rufus needed to download additional files to make the bootable drive work:

[image: Rufus screenshot]

If you didn't get this message (which may happen if you don't have an internet connection) or answered No, then you are expected to [run into the issue you describe](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/2233), as Ubuntu 23.04 requires the download of an external GRUB bootloader to work in Rufus.

So please make sure you use the latest Rufus (4.2 or later), run it on a PC that can connect to the internet and answer *Yes* when prompted with the message above.

Or, when prompted by Rufus whether you want to write the image in ISO or DD mode, select *DD mode*.